# German equivalent of "to do something about"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verb, phrase

There doesn't seem to be a translation on dict.cc. Is there a German equivalent of this phrase, or would you just have to use another verb or rephrase it in some way?

For example,

> You really should do something about that mosquito bite.
>
> Du solltest diesen Gelsenstich handeln.

Would this rephrase be more or less equivalent, or is there a better way to express this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your translation is almost correct: Depending on the country, I'd replace "Gelsen", because that is a local term. "Mückenstich" is a more generic term in German-speaking countries. And prefix "handeln" with "be-", making it

"Du solltest den Mückenstich behandeln (lassen)."

You could also say

"Du solltest etwas wegen des Mückenstichs tun/unternehmen."

Then, there is another way to say that, although it is somewhat colloquial:

"Du solltest etwas gegen den Mückenstich tun." (colloquial because of the construction "gegen...tun" - one can hardly so something "against" ("gegen") a mosquito bite; one can do something "about" ("wegen") it. But as "gegen...tun" is often used in spoken German and - as such - perfectly fine, I'd like to mention it here.)

Comment: *Gelse* is the Austrian term for *Mücke* "mosquito". And in General, *to do something about sth./so.* would correspond best to *etwas wegen/gegen/bezüglich etw./jmd. unternehmen/tun/machen*, it's not at all colloquial.

Comment: I marked it "colloquial" because of the "gegen...tun". Let's switch to German, makes more sense... Man kann wenig "gegen" einen Mückenstich tun, denn den hat man ja schon. Streng genommen kann man ihn behandeln, oder etwas gegen den Juckreiz - oder vielleicht sogar etwas *für* den Mückenstich tun (im Sinne von Behandeln, aber das wäre schon sehr gewagt). Aber "gegen den Mückenstich tun" finde ich zwar umgangssprachlich völlig üblich, aber in formell geschriebener Form leicht...bedenklich... :-) Daher - und nur in diesem Sinne - meine Anmerkung.

Comment: In Ordnung.. Ich hätte dann *gegen etwas tun* von *wegen etwas unternehmen* getrennt, ersteres ist tatsächlich umgangssprachlicher.

Comment: Geht in Ordnung :-) Ich habe die Antwort entsprechend besser formuliert. Vielen Dank für die nette und fruchtbare Diskussion!